# Random values in multidimensional-array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I get random item with it price on the below code and inserted to mysql as per radio botton choose if there are 4 bottons:

```
$class1 = array("Peugeot 404"=>5000,"Opel Diplomat"=>7500,"Honda Civic"=>10000,"Renault Megane"=>15000);
$class2 = array("Ford Mustang"=>22500,"Dodge Charger"=>36000,"Alfa GTV "=>90000,"Aston Martin Vanquish"=>102000);
$class3 = array("BMW 7 series"=>114000,"Ferrari F430"=>132000,"Pagani Zonda"=>150000,"Maserati Gran Turismo"=>168000);
$class4 = array("Bentley Continental R"=>180000,"Maybach"=>200000,"Rolls-Royce Phantom"=>300000);

$rand1 = array_rand($class1,4);
$rand2 = array_rand($class2,4);
$rand3 = array_rand($class3,4);
$rand4 = array_rand($class4,3);

if($_POST['do'])
{
    echo $_POST['car'];
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="car" id="<? $rand1 ?>" value="<? echo "You have won: ".$rand1[0]." AND Price: ".$class1[$rand1[0]].""; ?>" />Class 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="car" id="<? $rand2 ?>" value="<? echo "You have won: ".$rand2[0]." AND Price: ".$class2[$rand2[0]].""; ?>" />Class 2<br />
<input type="radio" name="car" id="<? $rand3 ?>" value="<? echo "You have won: ".$rand3[0]." AND Price: ".$class3[$rand3[0]].""; ?>" />Class 3<br />
<input type="radio" name="car" id="<? $rand4 ?>" value="<? echo "You have won: ".$rand4[0]." AND Price: ".$class4[$rand4[0]].""; ?>" />Class 4<br />
<input type="submit" name="do" value="DO" />
</form>
```

it is like a mafia game, when I select the first radio botton I get one of the randomly cars with it price. and the second botton give me also one items of the randomly cars but others model.

after that I need to insert it to mysql DB.